# Modifying and Re-compiling Linux Drivers

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, compiling

I'm interested in modifying and re-compiling one of the wireless drivers in a Linux environment. I know exactly which line in what file I need to modify, however **may I know how can I re-compile the source code from .c to .ko?** Correct me if i'm wrong, *the .ko file is how I am able to specify my modified wireless driver, i think.*

**[8/7/2018] - Edited for more information.**

I have edited the brcmfmac driver to transmit static data and I am trying to re-compile it. Therefore I would like to know how can I compile it into a .ko so that I can put this new driver into my openwrt device. I hope that clear things up. I am still in the midst of attempting to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can recompile kernel module by running `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules` command in module source directory.

Comment: Hi Karthik, thank you for your response. Is the driver source code supposed to be natively available in the driver files? I am only able to find the .ko driver file but not the source code itself. I am talking about the broadcom wireless driver, otherwise known as brcmfmac.

Comment: The source code of the `brcmfmac` driver is part of the Linux kernel source code package. In Linux kernel version 4.14, it is in directory `<kernel source package root>/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac`. In older kernels, the directory structure may be slightly different. If you are using the standard kernel of your Linux distribution, you'll need to install the corresponding `kernel-source` package, and often a `kernel-headers` package too. In distributions of Debian family, the package names are likely to be `linux-source` and `linux-headers` instead.

Comment: Generally /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r) folder contains only Kconfig and Makefile. You can Download driver source and build with above mentioned command.

Comment: @telcoM and karthik thank you for both your response. I will try the solution and post the outcome here tomorrow.

Comment: @Karthik, I was not able to fully compile the brcmfmac drivers due to a compilation error. However your reply has answered the question in the title I will just mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!